# Help with shortcode in admin-ajax

Tags: admin, shortcode, ajax

I've been playing around with ajax in wordpress and I've gotten my efforts to work on both back and front-end without too much trouble, however I've run into a problem getting post shortcodes to run when loading `post_content` to the front-end.

Here's what I've noticed:

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

..will run but it only wraps my shortcode in `<p>` tags, the way it does in the admin.

`do_shortcode()` will work when using `[gallery]` or other native wordpress shortcodes, but not the one i've registered in my plugin.

My plugin shortcode does however run in the normal wordpress post page (not ajax).

Having read about this, I'm aware that **admin-ajax.php** has **WP_ADMIN** set to **true** and so I think that what happening is that `apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );` runs differently depending on whether `is_admin` or not.

Either that or native shortcodes and plugin shortcodes `add_shortcode()` are registered differently and not accessible in the same places.

Does anyone have any insight on what's going on here?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're having trouble with?  Specifically the ajax callback and the portion of the code where you're calling `add_shortcode()` to register your custom shortcodes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that most likely you're adding the shortcodes on a hook that doesn't fire in an admin page. Would be helpful to see how you register it.

Answer (score -2):

How you are applying a filter is wrong. You need to bind a function to the filter, but you are providing a variable.

```
function my_filter( $content ) {
    return $content . 'My added code';
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_filter' );
```

You should add the code like this, this should work.